# Break string into multiple flowvars in mulesoft

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a String of 50 characters and I want to extract 3 smaller parts from it. I tried

```
%dw 1.0 %output application/json
 --- 
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {    
     id: payload01.substring(0,2),
      name: payload01.substring(2,14),
      age: payload01.substring(14,16)
 })
```

But that is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The "substring" operation on a string uses square brackets to denote position.

```
id: payload01[0..2]
```

Visit the Dataweave Operators doc for more information,
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#substring

Comment: I tried second ooption it doesnt work. getting error:

com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing: 
 payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {    
 ^
Type mismatch for 'map' operator
     found :string, :function
  required :array, :function.

My input string starts with something like
01Ram Prakash23

Comment: Can you post your complete input please? Is it a recurring element? If not then you will not need the "map" directive, just use, { id: payload[0..2],  name: payload[2..14], age: payload[14..16] }

Comment: this is a sample input, i am only concerned about id, name and age which is first 15 characters. "03Sri Prakash26 Arlington VA"

Comment: Did you try my previous comment about removing the map from the dw code. %dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
 id: payload[0..1],
 name: payload[2..14],
        age: payload[14..16]
}